# Maintaining the state of conversation in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger

I am building a facebook messenger bot which needs to take multiple inputs from the user. One way of storing all the inputs is to store them in database. However, I found a field "metadata" in the Send API request. The description of this field is also very promising - "Custom string that will be re-delivered to webhook listeners". However, when I fill this field with user inputs, I don't get them back with the next call.I used the sample app provided by Facebook to do this test.

Has anyone found a use for metadata property? Is it working?

Comment: The Message Echo Callback occurs when a message has been sent by your page, `text` messages or messages with `attachments`. The payload will include an optional custom `metadata` _developer defined custom string_ . Subscribe to this callback and check for this metadata. cheers

Comment: I am having the same problem that my metadata isn't being returned to me when the user replies to a message from my page.

If you find a solution please let me know!

Comment: There is no in-built mechanism to keep track of all the inputs of a chat user within the facebook API. We ended up storing the state in the database